# DISTINCT with GROUP BY in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, distinct

If I'm selecting distinct values, but then I group the results, are the values only distinct within each grouping, or across all groupings?

For example:

```
month | id
      |
  01  | 17 
  01  | 17 
  01  | 19
  04  | 17
  04  | 20
```

If I run

```
select month, count(distinct id)
from table
group by month
```

What counts will I get for the two months?

Comment: Why don't you just try it out?

Comment: distinct within the grouping. you'll get 01->2 and 02->2

Comment: you can use http://sqlfiddle.com/ to build the schema & try it out all in your browser.

Comment: @sgeddes I thought it might be good to have a question on SO for other peoples' reference. But you're right, I could have just answered my own question.

Answer (score 4):

You would get 2 for each month.

Here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9d267/2) showing the results.